# Magit WIP mode: how to suppress prompt about saving ~/.abbrevs?

Tags: magit

I recently started using `magit-wip-mode`, but it's got a feature that I'm finding very disruptive to my workflow: if I have defined an abbrev, which I do frequently, then saving any file with `C-x C-s` (`save-buffer`) interrupts me with a prompt asking if I want to save `~/.abbrevs`.  This interruption is making me crazy, to the point where I'm tempted just to turn off `magit-wip-mode`.

There must be a better way.  How can I tell `magit-wip-mode` not to ask about saving all modified buffers, or at least not to ask about saving this particular buffer?  (I suppose I could also think about modifying `save-some-buffers`, but I'm a little less easy in my mind about that.)

I'm happy to dive into the elisp code.  But where should I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to magit. Rather than tweeking it, you can tell abbrev-mode to be silent:

```
(setq save-abbrevs 'silently)
```

In addition, if you get interruptions to read the abbrev file, you can set:

```
(if (file-exists-p abbrev-file-name)
    (quietly-read-abbrev-file))
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who came to this question looking for an answer specific to magit, and not specific to the `~/.abbrevs` buffer, contrarily to the accepted answer:

Using `debug-on-entry` on the `save-some-buffers` function (which creates those prompts), we can see that `magit-wip-commit-buffer-file` calls `magit-wip-commit-worktree`, which calls `magit-maybe-save-repository-buffers`, whose doctring indicates that we can control its behavior with the variable `magit-save-repository-buffers`.

> If non-nil, then all modified file-visiting buffers belonging to the current repository may be saved before running Magit commands and before creating or refreshing Magit buffers. If ‘dontask’, then this is done without user intervention, for any other non-nil value the user has to confirm each save.
>
> The default is t to avoid surprises, but ‘dontask’ is the recommended value.

So if you want magit to save related buffers silently, you can use `(setq magit-save-repository-buffers 'dontask)`. Or if you only want to save the buffers that you explicitely save, use `(setq magit-save-repository-buffers nil)`. It will affect the behavior of magit in general, not only magit-wip.